I wish I'm pretty and confident
I am trying to explain to someone that is not fluent in English that saying:
I wish I'm pretty. Is not correct. I said:
I wish I was pretty. They replied that it is past tense and sounds wrong. How do I teach them this?

Or:  "I wish I were pretty".  So-called subjunctive.  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/subjunctive/

@GEdgar that just shifts the question as to why the present tense "I wish I be pretty" is also incorrect.

There is a place for "I be pretty."  Like this: "He commanded that I be pretty."  Subjunctive requires case in use.

@GEdgar I do not disagree that your "He commanded that I be pretty" can be seen as more idiomatic than "He commanded that I were pretty", but in the context of this question it looks like a reversed example of mixing a past and present tense.

@Henry He commanded, commands, has commanded, will command that I be pretty. Past tense isn't necessary.

Related: What is the etymology of WERE in the Second Conditional? and there's a bit of info in the Wikipedia article on Old English subjunctive.

You could try pointing out that the present indicative (here I’m) is used—primarily—to express things that are, or that are happening, at the time of the utterance. The fact that this person wishes to be pretty suggests that prettiness is not their current state, in which case present indicative doesn’t work.
The “officially correct” way to express the thought is I wish I were pretty.
By the way, what makes this person think I wish I was sounds funny if (apparently) I wish I am doesn’t?
Anyway, perhaps the most accurate answer you could give them is “That’s just the way English works. End of story.”
